# Switch between two versions of the same ActiveX IDispatch based interface at run-time in a Delphi 6 app?

Tags: delphi, dll, activex, typelib

I have a Delphi 6 app that uses an ActiveX DLL to interface to another popular app (aka the "host" app for lack of a better word).  The host app provides the integration DLL. I do not have the source code for it or any control over it.  To use the DLL I create a TypeLib using the IDE **Import ActiveX Control** facility.

The problem arises when the host app vendor creates a new version of the ActiveX DLL.  I have to scramble and provide my users with a new version of my program as they upgrade to the host app vendor's latest or beta versions.  Otherwise my app crashes of course when certain calls are made to the integration DLL due to variances between the old TypeLib and the new DLL.  This also leads to the burden of maintaining multiple code bases of my app  to maintain support for my users that still use the old versions of the host app.  I'm trying to avoid a big messy code overhaul where I wrap everything in sight exposed by the integration DLL, in order to create a version of my code that can adapt at run-time to the current DLL version.

That leads to my question.  The TypeLib(s) generated by Delphi is a big list of IDispatch methods and properties.  Apparently the Delphi compiler converts these to IDispatch.Invoke() calls behind the scenes.  Now I *can* detect the current version of the host app *before* I call CoCreate() to create the ActiveX object.  So, is there any way I can at run-time switch between the two DLL TypeLib definitions?  Right now I do it via compile-time conditionals that include the correct TypeLib based on the version of the host app I'm building for.  I can do this because I retain each version of the TypeLib and give it a unique name as the vendor updates the DLL. But that doesn't help me to do it at run-time.

I can't fathom how to do this because everything from defined variables to method calls is based on the TypeLib as it is compiled.  But I was wondering if there is something clever I could do at the IDispatch level to make this happen?  Otherwise I'm stuck creating wrappers for each exposed object that calls the correct TypeLib method/property definition based on the current version of the host app.  This is a big job and will also lead to some pretty convoluted code.

How have those of you faced with this same predicament solved or coped with it?

Comment: I'm not sure too many people have faced this predicament this century.  Q: Why are you forced to use such an old compiler (Delphi 6) and such old technology (typelibs and ActiveX)?  Q: Can you move into the 21st Century, or is that simply not an option?  Q: Why is this 3rd party *vendor* updating such old stuff???  Q: Does your product - and/or the 3rd party .dll - have a Windows version# you can check???

Comment: @paulsm4: Contrary to what you seem to think, there are still viable reasons to use ActiveX controls and type libraries. Not everything in the world is based on the .NET framework, and the Windows version number has absolutely nothing to do with this question (or the subject in general). The answer would be the same, whether the Windows version was 3.x or 7. (Granted, Delphi 6 is old, but the reason it's being used isn't meaningful here either, and Robert has explained that in prior posts.)

Comment: Windows *file version info* on the .dll and/or .exe could help mitigate version mismatches.

Comment: @paulsm4: Windows *file version* is not what you said in the comment I responded to, and proper *vendor* behavior (not changing the interface without also changing the GUID as well) would mitigate the version mismatches. Obviously that isn't being done here. :-)

Comment: What I don't understand is why you need a new typelib each time the host app changes. Doesn't the interface remain backwards compatible. Take Office. I can import the typelib for Office 2003 and use it to automate Office 2010. Can you do the same with your host app? If you can't then not even late binding will help you. Because how can you call objects whose interface you don't know.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The app vendor alters the interfaces but keeps the same GUIDs.  For example, last time they added a new method to one of the IDispatch based interfaces and the GUID did not change.  Why won't late binding help?  Isn't it late binding resolve a look-up by method name so it would get the updated DLL method offsets?  In regards to knowing the interface, re-importing the TypeLib from the latest DLL gets me the updated dispatch tables.

Comment: If all they do is add new methods, then late binding will be fine. If they change the signatures of published interfaces, then you are stuck. If they change the interface, but keep the GUID the same, isn't that completely bogus?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Then I'm OK because so far they have never altered the signature of the exposed methods.  I'll talk to them about this because your sentiments are what I always experienced in the past with OLE Automation Servers.  That is, "never break old contracts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The practical solution would be to use late binding (getting a reference using `CreateOleObject` and having the references resolved at runtime) instead of using early binding via the typelibs. This would mean that as long as the vendor doesn't remove functionality, your code would continue to work regardless of what version of the control was installed.

For examples of doing this with MS Office applications, you can see several of the old (but still accurate and usable) posts at [Deborah Pate's site](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoOffc.htm) (see note below). For instance, [this one](http://www.djpate.freeserve.co.uk/AutoWord.htm#HowDoI) for Word uses late binding to either retrieve the currently running Word instance or create a new one:

```
var 
  Word: Variant; 
  Filename: OleVariant;
begin 
  try 
    Word := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');    
  except 
    Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');    
  end; 

  FileName := 'C:\WordDocs\MyFile.doc';
  Word.Documents.Open(FileName, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                      EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                      EmptyParam, EmptyParam);  
  Word.Visible := True;
```

Note that there is no included type library here, and no prior declaration of `Word.Documents` or the `Documents.Open` method. These are both resolved for you at runtime, and if not implemented will raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks Ken, excellent idea and it works fine. To those that read this, you can find the name of the Automation server in your registry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. If you have trouble finding it, look for an entry that starts with the first few letters of the DLL that provides the OLE Automation server.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you can achieve the same effect with early binding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Can you explain how David?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Understood.  I'll keep an eye out for your future post.